# Compilation Failure when running as Maven Package

Tags: java, maven, javaw

I got this BUILD error when I run as Maven Package. But I'm not sure what's the error. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Conference Organizer
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 36 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Wallace\Desktop\co-app\co-app\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
C:\Users\Wallace\Desktop\co-app\co-app\src\main\java\com\alcatel\co\service\AdminControlService.java:[38,5] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 16 06:02:09 SGT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/34M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

"error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3"

Im guessing your code uses generics and the compiler is told to use java 1.3 which does not support such.

edit:
you might have to use at least java 1.5

```
 <project>
 [...]
   <build>
   [...]
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2</version>
     <configuration>
       <source>1.5</source>
       <target>1.5</target>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  [...]
  </build>
 [...]
 </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Maven POM:

```
<build>
  [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- set compliance level here -->
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  [...]
</build>
```

BTW, current versions of Maven assume 1.5 as default compliance level. Perhaps you should upgrade to a current Maven version.

Comment: Sorry, how do I add this? I see pom.xml. Do I add this in?

Comment: `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.alcatel</groupId>
    <artifactId>co-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Conference Organizer</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>`